# Just + simple past: "I just watched" vs. "I've just watched"

Tags: american-english, past-tense, british-english, present-perfect, past-simple

I don't know if I'm supposed to write an intro before the question since I'm new here lol I'd like to know if it's correct to use **just** followed by the simple past, e.g.:

> I **just watched** the first episode. (Simple Past)

I'm a little bit confused because I see people using both forms: this and

> I'**ve just watched** the first episode. (Present Perfect)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Marina! Did you mean to compare "I'**ve** just watched" to "I just watched" (Present Perfect and Present Simple)?

Comment: Thanks! Simple past requires a specific time, right? In that case, I could still use the simple past? I normally see "I've just watched" but "I just watched" appears a lot too. :)

Comment: A related question at ELU: "*[I just ate them v. I've just eaten them](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16081/i-just-ate-them-and-ive-just-eaten-them-whats-the-difference-in-american)*"

Answer (score 4):

It is not strictly necessary to use a specific time reference with the Past Simple.

It is the other way around: when you use the Present Perfect, you better not use a specific past time reference:

> I have watched this movie yesterday. (invalid sentence: the time period mentioned - "yesterday" - has already ended)

Concerning your question,

> I just watched the first episode.

Is an appropriatetly formed sentence in the American English. British English speakers prefer to use the Present Perfect:

> I've just watched the first episode.

---

Reference

1. [Comparison of American and British English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_American_and_British_English#Use_of_tenses) - Wikipedia
2. An [answer to a related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/16100/48335) at ELU.

Answer (score 1):

In normal good English, JUST used with the simple past means ONLY to the exclusion of anything else.
The word used with the past present ("have verb-ed") means the action was very recent.
The form Verb-ed used with a specific marker of time (as in the example above: 
I've just watched the first episode yesterday) is wrong and should be: I watched the first episode yesterday.

Compare:

> I have watched the first episode.
>
> I have never watched the first episode.
>
> I watched the first episode yesterday.
>
> Yesterday I watched JUST the first episode (and no other).
>
> I JUSY watch the first episode yesterday(and did nothing else).
>
> I watched the first episode recently/yesterday.
>
> I watched the first episode JUST / ONLY (as recently as) yesterday.
>
> I have watched only the first episode.
>
> I have watched JUST the first episode (and no other)
>
> I have watched just the first episode.

For many people JUST and ONLY are troublesome. These words limit the scope of what immediately follows.

> I JUST watered the flowers (that's all I did).
>
> I watered ONLY / JUST the flowers (and watered nothing else).
>
> I have JUST watered the flowers (very recent).
>
> ONLY I watered / have watered the flowers (and nobody else).

Etc., etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's in a Present Perfect form; it's just normal to put 'have' right after the subject. we also include adverbial phrase (already,yesterday) at the end of the sentence for Present perfect. I think it's better to say "I've just watched the first episode yesterday".

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Could you please be more elaborate on why an adverbial phrase would be better? Maybe also support your claims with a source?