# They just/They've just

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

Someone has contacted me on the phone. After I hang up I call someone else and says:

> They/They've just contacted me.

Should it be "They just..." or "They've just..."?

What is correct? What is natural?

Comment: We expect people to do a little research before asking a question. In this case, you could look at the difference between past simple (they just) and present perfect (they've just). This site may help you: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/present-perfect If you don't find  the answer, please update your question to provide details of your research, and explain what exactly you still don't understand.

Comment: Are you learning American or British English? I would say that someone _has just done_ something, but I believe Americans are more likely to say that they _just did_ it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Have just finished' vs. 'Just finished': What is the difference?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/107186/have-just-finished-vs-just-finished-what-is-the-difference) Also [I have just got vs. I just got](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/273172/i-have-just-got-vs-i-just-got) and [Just + simple past: “I just watched” vs. “I've just watched”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44691/just-simple-past-i-just-watched-vs-ive-just-watched), among others.

Comment: (If those linked questions don't explicitly point it out, the presence of a word like ***just*** makes it more likely the past action has ***current relevance***, which more strongly supports using Present Perfect instead of Simple Past.)